# EOS Rebel T100 compatible 300 or 400 mm lense

Tags: canon, wildlife, nature, bird-photography

I am thinking about getting a refurbished [Refurbished EOS Rebel T100](https://www.usa.canon.com/shop/p/refurbished-eos-rebel-t100-ef-s-18-55mm-f-3-5-5-6-iii-lens-kit). Is it compatible with [Canon EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 III Telephoto Zoom Lens](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00004THD0)?  Also, what is the cheapest way I can go up to 400mm?

Thanks.

Comment: While I've closed this as a duplicate of our canonical EF vs EF-S compatibility question, I'd also strongly recommend reading [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/39252/11371) (disclaimer: written by me) on whether you should buy the 75-300 at all (tl;dr: no)

Comment: @PhilipKendall side note: looks like https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13852, https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/35171, and https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39243 are all possible duplicates. Could be more.

Comment: @inkista I'd argue they're not duplicates of the question as asked ("Is the EF 75-300 compatible with with Rebel T100?"). They are good additional information to support my rant about the 75-300 though :)

Comment: @PhilipKendall, Oh, not duplicates of *this* question; duplicates of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Canon T100/4000D is compatible with EF 75-300. And if you want to reach 400mm for this sensor you will have it because equivalent focal length of this lens on this body is 480mm.

But you may have challenge with autofocus which may not work on long focal lengths (on this camera it will work fine till f5.6)

If you want to reach 400mm (real value) IMHO there is no cheap way. Maybe you can use mirror lens but they are manual focus and there is probability the image quality will not make you happy.

Comment: I doubt the image quality of the 75-300mm will make the OP happy either. It's probably the worst lens in Canon's entire current catalog.

Comment: @MichaelC, I do not have first hand experience with these lens. Just answer the OPs question...