# Difference in cameras and lenses

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon

I'm interested in the difference between the following two camera kits:

- Canon EOS Rebel T3i SLR Camera with EF-S 18-55 IS II lens and EF-S 55-250 f/4-5.6 IS zoom lens
- Canon EOS Rebel T3i SLR Camera with EF-S 18-55 IS II lens and EF 75-300 f/4-5.6 III zoom lens

I need a camera for sports pictures with the best zoom capabilities from far away.

Comment: Since most of that string is the same, are you actually asking "What's the difference between the Canon EF-S 55-250 f/4-5.6 and the EF 75-300 f/4-5.6 for distant sports?"

Answer (score 2):

The EF 75-300 f/4-5.6 III will get you a little closer, but the EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS is better optically and has Image Stabilization which will help in certain situations. While it is true that IS is primarily for dealing with camera movement issues, the Mode 2 IS option of the 55-250 is very helpful for doing horizontal panning shots at slower than normal shutter speeds for typical action shots.

For a much more detailed comparison of the EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 III vs. the EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS see [Canon 75-300mm f4-5.6 USM or 55-250mm f4-5.6 IS lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/35171/canon-75-300mm-f4-5-6-usm-or-55-250mm-f4-5-6-is-lens/35175#35175)